# How to change the text size and orientation of a spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I need to change the text size and orientation of the selected item shown on a spinner, but also I need to continue using the default layout for the spinner: android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Why? Because if I use personalized layout, I can't load dynamically generated arrays of strings on the spinner. It is a fail of Android :S

can someone help me please?

Comment: I don't think it's fail of Android, I think you didn't invest enough time to understand how to use spinner correctly. It works fine with dynamically added items even if you use custom item layout.

Comment: inazaruk, it is nice to say: "it works", but if you take a time to read my post you will understand that i tryed to do it, searching a lot of stackoverflow and google and i didn't find the way to do it, because this, i open this question. Then if, you know how to do it... tell how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it's a little tricky, but not too hard.

1. Extend `SimpleAdapter`, creating a custom adapter.
2. Make sure that you implement `SpinnerAdapter` in this new adapter. (if you are using Eclipse, let it help you by creating unimplemented methods)
3. Implementing `SpinnerAdapter` will force you to add a dropdown view resource xml object. Add it statically, or define a setter.
4. Inside `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` (which is where you return a custom view to the Spinner), call `parent.getSelectedItem()` to see if it is the same as the item at `position` in your list.
5. If it is, set your font bigger. If not, set it normal (don't forget to do this, as the spinner will recycle views, leaving your bigger font in place).

To use the adapter, call something like this from your Activity:

```
MyCustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(this, myListOfItems);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_dropdown_view_resource);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To see how google does it, take a look in google codesearch [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/) and search for "Android ArrayAdapter.java" - Click on the core/java/android/widget link and it'll take you to the package that has all the various adapters, interfaces and widgets that you need to figure the rest out.

Good luck.

EDIT: Here is an untested first crack at it as an example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.beget.consumer.R;

public class MyCustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

    private String[] list;
    private Context context;

    public MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, String[] list) {
        super();
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //you need to add index safety here - make sure that position is a valid index
        return list[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = context.inflate(R.layout.my_view_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.myView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.beget_box_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        if (list[position] == ((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem()) {
            holder.myView.setTextSize(25);
        } else {
            holder.myView.setTextSize(15);
        }

        holder.myView.setText(list[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //change this if you want a different view for your dropdown list. It's the same as above, except you could 
        //inflate a different view if you wanted.
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView myView;
    }

}
```

Comment: i dont understand how to do this, it is too munch hard for my skills. I'm trying to find examples and help on google but it is not possible to find them. I think that this answer is not possible to get implemented correctly and working.

Comment: I've added an (untested) example. It should pretty much do what you want. No guarantees, however!